# Flat UI, Bootstrap Responsive Design Issues

Tags: responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am in the process of getting familiar with the Twitter Bootstrap framework and also Flat UI but I am having some unexpected functionality with a responsive layout. I don't think the problem is caused by Flat UI as the same thing happens even when removing those references.

I have 2 columns  which are both 50% width using class="span6". At full screen (large monitor) the design looks how I would expect but if I slowly decrease my browser width the columns go from floated to stacked, then back to floated and then finally back to stacked again! I would expect them to remain floated until the screen width is not sufficient and then change to stacked so I can't understand the multiple changes. I have set up a [little demo here](http://www.thinkbigsoftware.co.uk/bootstrap/default.html).

Can anybody please provide any reasons why this would be happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the 3.0.0 version of bootstrap for bootstrap.css and 2.3.2 for the bootstrap-responsive.css.

Bootstrap 3.0 has deprecated the use of span* in the CSS now. You need to download and use 2.3.2 for the bootstrap.css as well (if you intend to use span* etc)

You can get the 2.3.2 bootstrap.css from [here](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css), you should use that and replace the current 3.0.0 bootstrap.css you are using.

Comment: This explains so much, thanks Ryan! I'll blame that on the poor Flat UI docs!